# literate-calc-mode gave me false results

Tags: org-mode, calc, literate-calc--mode

I'm just discovering `literate-calc-mode` which looks cool. I tested on a small elementary geometry problem to calculate the radius of the circle circumscribed by a triangle whose sides are given.

This is the document I used for testing `literate-calc-minor-mode`.
The radius of the circumscribed circle is 8.125 units, and `literate-calc-mode` result is 25.5

My Emacs version is 28.2 on Debian bookworm 12.4 I  launched by
emacs -q

```
#+TITLE: Test literate-calc-mode
#+NAME: test-literate-calc.org

* COMMENT Préambule

#+begin_src emacs-lisp 
  (require 'literate-calc-mode)
#+end_src

* Problème
[[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSv0Kv3OA88&t=2s][Find Radius]]

* Calculs
** Données
a=15
b=13
c=14
** Demi-périmètre
p=(a+b+c)/2
* Aire du triangle
A=sqrt(p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c))
** Rayon du cercle circonscrit
R=abc/4A
*Faux*

* Valeur exate:
=13*14*15/4*84
```

As you can see by evaluating `M-x literate-calc-minor-mode` the radius calculation gives an inaccurate result: 45.5 when it should be 8.125.
What mistake did I make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the formula to R=a, check the result, and you will see the problem.

Comment: Great! I didn't suspect this since Calc is case sensitive.

Comment: You can use long names for variables (e.g. `area`).